# Metamodelling tools

Tags: model-driven

What tools are available for metamodelling?

Especially for developing diagram editors, at the moment trying out [Eclipse GMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmf/)

Wondering what other options are out there? 
Any comparison available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is simply too broad for a single answer - due to many aspects.

First, meta-modelling is not a set term, but rather a very fuzzy thing, including modelling models of models and reaching out to terms like MDA.

Second, there are numerous options to developing diagram editors - going the Eclipse way is surely a nice option.

To get you at least started in the Eclipse department:

- have a look at MOF, that is architecture for "meta-modelling" from the OMG (the guys, that maintain UML)
- from there approach EMOF, a sub set which is supported by the Eclipse Modelling Framework in the incarnation of Ecore.
- building something on top of GMF might be indeed a good idea, because that's the way existing diagram editors for the Eclipse platform take (e.g. Omondo's EclipseUML)
- there are a lot of tools existing in the Eclipse environment, that can utilize Ecore - I simply hope, that GMF builts on top of Ecore itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Dia](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/) has an API for this - I was able to fairly trivially frig their UML editor into a basic ER modelling tool by changing the arrow styles.  With a DB reversengineering tool I found in sourceforge (took the schema and spat out dia files) you could use this to document databases.  While what I did was fairly trivial, the API was quite straightforward and it didn't take me that long to work out how to make the change.

If you're of a mind to try out Smalltalk There used to be a Smalltalk meta-case framework called [DOME](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/nectar-adamb/web/DomeRelease.html) which does this sort of thing.  If you download [VisualWorks](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com), DOME is one of the contributed packages.

Answer (score 1):

GMF is a nice example. At the core of this sits [EMF/Ecore](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/), like computerkram sais. Ecore is also used for the base of Eclipse's  [UML2](http://www.eclipse.org/uml2) . The prestige use case and proof of concept for GMF is certainly [UML2 Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2tools).

Answer (score 0):

Although generally a UML tool, I would look at [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/). It supports [additional modules beyond what are already built in](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/modules.php). If it doesn't have what you need built in or as a module, I supposed you could make your own, but I don't know how difficult that is.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-modeling is mostly done in Smalltalk.

You might want to take a look at MOOSE (http://moose.unibe.ch). There are a lot of tools being developed for program understanding. Most are Smalltalk based. There is also some java and c++ work.

Two of the most impressive tools are CodeCity and Mondrian. CodeCity can visualize code development over time, Mondrian provides scriptable visualization technology.

And of course there is the classic HotDraw, which is also available in java.

For web development there is also Magritte, providing meta-descriptions for Seaside.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you look into DSM (Domain Specific Modeling) as a general topic, meta-modeling is directly related.  There are eclipse based tools like GMF that currently require java coding, but integrate nicely with other eclipse tools and UML.  However there are two other classes out there.

1. MetaCase which I will call a pure DSM tool as it focuses on allowing a developer/modeler with out nearly as much coding create a usable graphical model.  Additionally it can be easily deployed for others to use.  GMF and Microsoft's Beta software factory/DSM tool fall into this category.
2. Pure Meta-modeling tools which are not intended for DSM tooling, code generation, and the like.  I do not follow these tools as closely as I am interested in applications that generate tooling for SMEs, Domain Experts, and others to use and contribute value to an active project not modeling for models sake, or just documentation and theory.

If you want to learn more about number 1, the tooling applications for DSMs/Meta-modeling, then check out my post ["DSMForum.org great resources, worth a look."](http://modelarchitecture.blogspot.com/2009/05/dsmforumorg-great-resources-worth-look.html) or just navigate directly to the DSMForum.org

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in something that is related to modelling and not generation of code, have a look at [adoxx.org](http://www.adoxx.org). As a metamodelling platform it does provide functionalities and mechanisms to quickly develop your own DSL and allows you to focus on the models needs (business requirements, conceptual level design/specification). There is an active community from academia and practice involved developing prototypical as well as commercial application based on the platform. Could be interesting ...